# iOS UITableView Index is transparent

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

As shown in the below image, I have set the table's background and some other styles. The index, highlighted in red, is transparent. How do I set it to be white like the rest of the cell?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you set accessory view to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone. Do the accessories disappear?

Comment: The Index letters on the right still have the table's background, not a solid white

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    its too much easy dude.

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


        for(UIView *view in [tableView subviews])
        {
            if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
            {
            [view performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];

//give color which you want 
            }
        }



        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";


    //go further with table cell design...

    }
```

Comment: This is poor way to do it and may be rejected by Apple. If apple changes their internal implementation of the TableView in new iOS version it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the designated UITableView properties:

```
tableView.sectionIndexColor = [UIColor brownColor];
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Messing around with the underlying TableView layers will likely reject your app and may break if Apple changes their UITableView implementation.